# Derived table not allowed for delete

Tags: sql, teradata

**My data looks like -**

```
+-------+------------+------------+
|  ID   | START_DATE |  END_DATE  |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 12345 | 11/09/2008 | 02/02/2011 |
| 12345 | 11/09/2008 | 11/09/2008 |
| 12345 | 02/02/2011 | 12/31/9999 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

**How I want it to be -**

```
+-------+------------+------------+
|  ID   | START_DATE |  END_DATE  |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 12345 | 11/09/2008 | 02/02/2011 |
| 12345 | 02/02/2011 | 12/31/9999 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Basically I am deleting the duplicates under column **ID** and **START_DATE** and keeping the latest **END_DATE** one

**My Query -** *Using this I can see the duplicates*

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, START_DATE order by END_DATE desc) RN
 FROM MYTABLE) a WHERE a.RN>1
```

The above **SELECT** query works just fine but when I try to **DELETE** using same query like this -

```
 DELETE FROM (SELECT ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, START_DATE order by END_DATE desc) RN
 FROM MYTABLE) a WHERE a.RN>1
```

**I get prompted with -**

> ERROR [42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database]
>   Syntax error: derived table not allowed for delete.

**My ask -**

Is there a way I can delete those dupes without going into derived tables or any other way to transform the current query without using derived tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have duplicates on `(id, start_date, end_date)`, then you can do:

```
delete from mytable t
    where t.end_date < (select max(t2.end_date)
                        from mytable t2
                        where t2.id = tid and t2.start_date = t.start_date
                       );
```

Comment: This is deleting all the records.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete record that first query selects and use their ID:

```
Delete from MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (
 SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, START_DATE order by END_DATE desc) RN
 FROM MYTABLE) a WHERE a.RN>1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this delete the both the records? Since the ID will match with both the entries.